# Oracle - XMLTABLE PATH get node ancestor

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, oracle12c, xmltable

I have  XML that looks like:

```
<root>
    <uid>789</uid>
    <element>
      <uid>123</uid>
         <sub>
             <text>XYZ</text>
         </sub>
     </element>
</root>
```

The only constant thing is `<text>` node and the fact that `<uid>` node could be 2 level up. Rest of nodes could have any name so I cannot use fully qualified paths.

Based of `<text>` node I need to find `<uid>` node which is the nearest or for simplicity 2 levels up in the tree.

I tried:

```
WITH cte("XML") AS (
  SELECT '<root>
             <uid>789</uid>
           <element>
            <uid>123</uid>
            <sub>
                <text>XYZ</text>
            </sub>
            </element>
         </root>'
  FROM dual
)
SELECT x.*, c.*
FROM cte c,XMLTable('//text'
          PASSING XMLTYPE(c."XML")
          COLUMNS
           text VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '.'
            --,guid VARCHAR2(40) PATH '../../uid'  -- unsupported XQuery expression
            --,guid VARCHAR2(40) PATH 'ancestor::node()[2]/uid'  
             -- unsupported XQuery expression\
                 ) x  
WHERE text IS NOT NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=825e10c232f127b4e43bbb8c00971a79)**

I am looking for solution similar to SQL Server:

```
WITH cte("XML") AS (
  SELECT CAST('<root>
             <uid>789</uid>
           <element>
            <uid>123</uid>
            <sub>
                <text>XYZ</text>
            </sub>
            </element>
         </root>' AS XML)
)
SELECT x.value('../../uid[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS uid
     ,s.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS "text"
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY c."XML".nodes('//text') s(x)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca8ffd27936afdef4c0fe51381ff96ae)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `preceding` - it will return all nodes except any ancestor.
Order of preceding collection is from the beginning to the end.
If you do this `preceding::uid` or more general `preceding::*` result will be (789, 123).

Combining everything together:

```
WITH cte("XML") AS (
  SELECT '<root>
             <uid>789</uid>
           <element>
            <uid>123</uid>
            <sub>
                <text>XYZ</text>
            </sub>
            </element>
         </root>'
  FROM dual
)
SELECT x.*, c.*
FROM cte c,XMLTable('//text'
          PASSING XMLTYPE(c."XML")
          COLUMNS
           text VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '.'
           ,guid VARCHAR2(40) PATH '(preceding::uid)[last() -1]/data(.)'  -- 2 -levelup            
                 ) x  
WHERE text IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

One working solution is the following:

```
SELECT x.*, c.*
FROM cte c,XMLTable('//text/../..'
               PASSING XMLTYPE(c."XML")
               COLUMNS
                 text VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'uid',
                 guid VARCHAR2(40) PATH 'sub/text'
               ) x  
WHERE text IS NOT NULL;
```

Its result consists of the two columns `123` and `XYZ`.

Comment: I modified it a bit to make it independent of 'sub' node name and it is working. **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=356cbe5a1c36dfaf92443851dcfa6e99)**